# Parsing Soundcloud Source with BeautifulSoup

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup

I'm going to keep it simple. I am decently new to HTML/JS. It's not complicated but I just don't have the syntax down for BeautifulSoup down to the point of knowing how to properly parse specific information.

```
<a href="/buygore/k-theory-x-wizard-turn-it?in=blissful-edm/sets/best" class="trackItem__trackTitle sc-link-dark sc-font-light">K Theory X Wizard - Turn It</a>
```

So, above is the specific tag I want to get information out of. Specifically the actual artist - song name portion near the end of the text which is "K Theory X Wizard - Turn It" in this instance. Would I have to use regular expressions? To get the link in this situation I could just specify I want the value attached to href, but I don't see anything attached to the text above. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `findAll` on the soup to get the result.

```
f = soup.findAll("a", {"class":"trackItem__trackTitle sc-link-dark sc-font-light")

print(f.text)
```

This should work